# Java 8 Need advice with stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a List:

```
class DummyClass {
  List<String> rname;
  String name;

}
```

The values in my List look like this:

```
list.add(DummyClass(Array.asList("a","b"),"apple"))
list.add(DummyClass(Array.asList("a","b"),"banana"))
list.add(DummyClass(Array.asList("a","c"),"orange"))
list.add(DummyClass(null,"apple"))
```

I want to convert the above List into a Map<String,  Set>, where key is rname and value is Set of name field.

```
{
"a"-> ["apple", "orange", "banana"],
"b"-> ["apple", "banana"]
"c" -> ["orange"]
}
```

I am trying to use java stream and facing null pointer exception . Can someone please guide

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map =
    list.stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DummyClass::rname, 
                                                Collectors.mapping(DummyClass::getName,
                                                                   Collectors.toSet())));
```

I am not able to process {(Array.asList("a","b"))}each element of list in stream.
There is some flaw here :

```
Collectors.groupingBy(DummyClass::rname, 
                                                    Collectors.mapping(DummyClass::getName,
                                                                       Collectors.toSet())))
```

where I am processing the entire list together, rather than each element . Shall I use another stream

Comment: Please see [mcve] and fix your question accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand the output. Why is nothing mapped to banana?

Comment: @shmosel updated the output

Comment: What do you want to do with `list.add(DummyClass(null,"apple"))`? Ignore it or map `null` to "apple"?

Comment: @Eran ignore if list is null

Comment: Since you are grouping by a `List<String>` key, the resulting map is a `Map<List<String>, Set<String>>`, not a `Map<String, Set<String>>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a filter - many of the util classes to construct collections no longer allow null e.g. `Map.of` or the `groupingBy` you have above.
You can filter or first map, replace null with a string and then group by.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map =
list.stream().filter(v-> v.getName() != null)
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DummyClass::rname, 
                                            Collectors.mapping(DummyClass::getName,
                                                               Collectors.toSet())));
```

Or if you don't want to drop null values, do a map and produce a key that all null names can be grouped under something like:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map =
list.stream().map(v-> Map.entry(v.getName() == null? "null": v.getName(), v))
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                               Collectors.toSet())));
```

The `groupingBy` that I have above needs to be changed as it now has a `Map.Entry` rather than your desired type.

I'm writing this on a mobile...without an editor so will leave that part to you :)

Comment: StreamEx makes this type of mapping much cleaner: `StreamEx.of(list).mapToEntry(d -> d.rname, d -> d.name).flatMapKeys(List::stream).grouping(toSet())`

Comment: @zcourts
collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DummyClass::rname,

This would return the entire list 

So the output would be Map<List<String>, Set<String>> rather than Map<String, Set<String>>

Comment: @RiKh it's not working code, only meant to exemplify the `.stream().map` and `.stream().filter` you need. What follows needs some refactoring - groupBy `Map.Entry::getKey` won't produce a list if refactored properly

Comment: @RiKh `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DummyClass::rname,…` is exactly what you have posted in your question, which does indeed result in a `Map<List<String>, Set<String>>`. It’s an error already existing in your question’s code. This answer only inserted a `filter` operation which doesn’t affect the types at all.